# How to set subject and message part in email with attachment while share charm usage in XAML/C# Windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, share

my app has share charm. It is used to share files and rich text. I have set `Title` (TextBlock) and `Description` (RichEditBox) properties and used `SetStorageItems()` & `SetRtf()` methods to share files of class [`DataPackage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205873.aspx), but while using mail app in share charm the `Title` should be fill as subject and the `Description` should be set as body of email but it is not working, please help me.

If I use only `SetText()` then it sets automatically.

PS : Here the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84) for sharing source content

Comment: I don't think we'll have a solution to this until they come up with a standard email DataPackage format to [StandardDataFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.standarddataformats.aspx) and support it in the email app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Microsoft's default Mail should be upgraded. If sharing experience is best one then user will user default Mail app otherwise they will go for another mail apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet. There is no standard way to share structured email forms.